# setInterval issues with Chrome and Firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox, google-chrome, setinterval

I'm having an issue with a site I'm working on. It's not only this site but another one that I have made with a Jquery slider. They both have different plugins. Issue is that when you change tabs the slider gets all crazy when you go back... especially in Chrome. the site is http://www.firedogpr.com/index.php. I've read about this issue but I'm no JS wizard, so any help would be greatly appreciated.

For some reason, it currently does not work in Windows at all. I'm also looking into that.

I've basically taken the code from http://www.snowdenindustries.com and adapted it. here is the snippet of js that may be the issue

```
if ($("#mainSlide").length>0) {
    $("#mainSlide div.slide").hide();
    $("#mainSlideNav li a:first").addClass("cur");
    $("#mainSlide div.slide:first").show();


    $("#mainSlideNav li a").click(function() {
        $("#mainSlideNav li a").removeClass("cur");
        $(this).addClass("cur");
        $("#mainSlide div.slide").removeClass("cur").fadeOut(1200);
        var activeTab = $(this).attr("href");
        $(activeTab).fadeIn(1200).addClass("cur");
        return false;
    });

    function slideTimer() {
        if (!($('#mainSlideNav li a.cur').parent().next().children("a").length>0)) {
            $("#mainSlideNav li a").removeClass("cur");
            $("#mainSlide div.slide").removeClass("cur").fadeOut(1200);
            $("#mainSlideNav li a:first").addClass("cur");
            $("#mainSlide div.slide:first").fadeIn("slow").addClass("cur");
        } else {
            var nextTab = $('#mainSlideNav li a.cur').parent().next().children("a").attr('id');
            var nextDiv = $('#mainSlide div.slide:visible').next().attr('id');
            $("#mainSlide div.slide").removeClass("cur").fadeOut(1200);
            $("#mainSlideNav li a").removeClass("cur");

            $("#"+nextTab).addClass("cur");
            $("#"+nextDiv).fadeIn("slow").addClass("cur");
        }
    }
    var miniCount = setInterval( slideTimer, 5000);
    $("#mainSlideNav li a, #mainHeader").mouseenter( function(){
        clearInterval(miniCount);});
    $("#mainSlideNav,  #mainHeader").mouseleave( function(){
        clearInterval(miniCount);
        miniCount = setInterval(slideTimer, 5000);});
}
```

Comment: what role does setinterval() play here ???

Comment: Updated post. Sorry guys, pressed enter too soon.

Comment: @DoctypeDesigner: Code that is not properly indented does not encourage others to help you

Comment: Sorry! I don't usually post code here... I hope I did it right? Looks ok to me. The editor seemed a bit confusing on that part.

Comment: @DoctypeDesigner: I fixed it! But it's still very hard to tell what the problem is. I went to the website and have no clue what I'm supposed to do to reproduce the problem. There are no tabs

Comment: When I visit your URL right now, the buttons I'm assuming deal with the slider (5 circles) are not being canceled and just get added to the URL hash.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The jQuery documentation explicitly says to not use the jQuery animation APIs (like fadeIn) from an interval timer, precisely because they APIs that jQuery uses are suspended in background tabs, so you end up running multiple fade-ins at once.

At least in the old jQuery you're using; I believe current jQuery fixes that problem.

Comment: Thanks... I'll try out a new fresh jQuery and see if it helps. I'm confused because it doesn't happen to Snowden industries at all, and when I stripped it down to the very basic part that I need it starts doing that.

Comment: So it was an out-dated jquery... Got the most recent and everything is fine now :). Still have the Chrome bug where it won't load background images, but I know that's a Chromium issue. I also didn't know that I forgot to overwrite the main.js file to the most recent change, Chrome saved the cache for me and I didn't clear it so it seemed to be working for me, but not for you guys, sorry about that.